# Unity|Moving gameobjects away from other gameobjects which are moving towards them

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 AI game objects which are both capsules. Considering the first capsule AI is named X and the second capsule AI is named Y, I try to make Y move away from X (escape from him) while X is chasing Y (following him). I have no idea how to do that, I would appreciate a direction.

I tried to do what's written here, but they both move through walls even though they have capsule collider, I tried to do this:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/getting-objects-to-move-away-from-my-users-gameobject.142468/

but they only move in one direction and through walls.

```
Vector3 position = transform.position;
Vector3 targetPosition = target.transform.position;
Vector3 direction = position - targetPosition;
transform.position += direction * 2.0f * Time.deltaTime;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving them with transform.Translate. Moving the transform means "Put the object at the given position regardless of environment". If you want them to interact, you need to either use the CharacterController component and its methods or a rigidbody component and move it with force.

Comment: Thanks :), and how do I make my gameobjects be able to move to different directions and not only to the right?

Comment: I'd need your code to see why it only moves right. You should add it to the question.

Comment: They are both AI. That's why I am having difficulties having them turn around and make routes. So yea, it is straight right from the other gameobject which is an AI as well.

Comment: Ok so now I am confused. If it is straight right then it does what it should I guess. One thing I see wrong (but maybe is not), direction should be the other way around. To get the direction from A to B you do B - A, but your vector is position to target.

Comment: I understand that one follows the other. So you need the other to change route, we need the code of the other guy then as well.

Comment: So I assume to make them move right and left while still moving away from a specific gameobject I should have an entire different code? And how do I do that? Is it complex?

Comment: The other's code is simply a vector3 move towards.
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targets[0].transform.position, speed);

Comment: Well, the leading guy should have more complexity to allow the target point to be changed. I understand you have a 2D game, and those two guys are running away from what could be the player. The player can be left or right of them. In this case, the leading is just using the direction (position - player) so that it always goes opposite  characterController.Move((transform.position - player.position)) , the following guy is just looking at the leader to know where to go characterController.Move((leader.position - transform.position)).